# How to use logical XOR operator in macro? NOT how to defined XOR operator by macro

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macros, logical-operators

Is there any tricky way to use logical xor operator `^^` in macro in C, C++, Objective-C?

I have tried applying `^^` directly in Objective-C, it does not work.

Edited: let me clarify my answer.

What I want is to use xor operator **in macro**. It does not mean "how to define the xor operator by a macro.

I.e, I want something like

```
#if defined(x) ^^ TARGET_OS_IOS ^^ __cplusplus
```

Comment: There is no logical XOR operator in C or C++

Comment: how about `!=`?

Comment: By summoning a minimum of C programming knowledge, you can write such an operator yourself, in less than 10 seconds. `#define XOR(a,b) ( ((a)!=0) ^ ((b)!=0) )`.

Comment: @Lundin: my question is to use logical xor operan **IN MACRO**. I also want to use it though multiple file. With your solution, I have to include the header file including that macro, of course, it is not efficient

Comment: @tranvansang Macros are evaluated by the pre-processor, making them very efficient. But you don't _have_ to implement it as a macro, you can simply use `((a)!=0) ^ ((b)!=0)` anywhere in the code. It yields the very same machine code.

Comment: @lundin: why not `(!(a) ^ !(b))`

Comment: @tranvansang The only difference is that `!` doesn't promote the operand and always returns an `int`. `!=` promotes the operand. I don't think it matters in your case.

Answer (score 2):

For seconds after posting the question, I figured out the answer my self.

`!(A) != !(B)` will be equivalent to xor operator

A better solution in case the number of operands is different than 2

`!(A) ^ !(B) ^ !(C) ^ ...`

Comment: You can remove the ! infront of the variables `A != B` should also do the job

Comment: @Aeonos The `!` are necessary if `A` and `B` are integer types other than `bool`. Consider `A=1; B=2`